# What is causing one block of code to loop and the other not?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So as a learning assignment in working with python I am to create a basic tic-tac-toe program.

My question is between these two blocks of code:

```
letter = ''
while (letter != 'X' or letter != 'O'):
    letter = raw_input("Player 1 select your letter (X or O)")
    letter = letter.upper()
if letter == 'X':
    return ['X','O']
else:
    return ['O','X']
```

and

```
letter = ''
while not (letter == 'X' or letter == 'O'):
    letter = raw_input("Player 1 select your letter (X or O)")
    letter = letter.upper()
if letter == 'X':
    return ['X','O']
else:
    return ['O','X']
```

As you can see there is only one difference between the blocks of code, specifically the second line of each block.

The first block of code regardless of what the user inputs, gets stuck in the loop and continuously asks the user what letter they want.

The second block of code works as intended.

Can you please explain why this is the case as to my understanding the line in the first code reads the same as the second.

Thank you.

Comment: Because logically, *not (X or Y)* is not equivalent to *not X or not Y*. In the first case, `letter != 'X' or letter != '0'` always evaluates to `True`, since the letter cannot be both `X` and `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fundamental logic, which you will get better at with practice.

```
letter != 'X' or letter != 'O'
```

Imagine a letter - any letter. Let's first pick `'X'`. It does not satisfy the first expression of `letter != 'X'`, but it does satisfy the second expression of `letter != 'O'`. Now let's try `'O'`. That satisfies the first expression but not the second. Now try it with any character other than `'X'` or `'O'`, like `'N'`. That satisfies both expression. No matter what you pick, the condition will be satisfied and the loop will always execute.

```
letter == 'X' or letter == 'O'
```

Here, only `'X'` will satisfy the first expression, and only `'O'` will satisfy the second. No other value will satisfy the condition. This means that the loop will only execute if `letter` is `'X'` or `'O'`.

The first code block could be repaired as follows:

```
letter != 'X' and letter != 'O'
```

This means that if the letter isn't `'X'` *and* the letter isn't `'O'`, the loop will execute. `'X'` or `'O'` will stop execution.

You could also use this condition:

```
letter not in 'XO'
```

If `letter` is not a member of that string, the loop will execute. Note that this would break if `letter` is literally `'XO'` - if you don't trust the user, you should make an adjustment:

```
letter not in {'X', 'O'}
```

It's a little larger, but also safer if you expect the possibility of multiple-character inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the condition `letter != 'X' or letter != 'O'`.  This condition can literally never be false.  You probably meant `and` instead of `or`.

If `letter` is neither `'X'` nor `'O'` then clearly the condition is true (satisfied by the first test).  If it's `'O'` then the condition is still true, still satisfied by the first test.  And the only other possibility, `letter == 'X'` is *also* true, satisfied by the second test.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `(letter != 'X' or letter != 'O')` is not equivalent to `not (letter == 'X' or letter == 'O')`.

Suppose `letter` is equal to `'X'`:

- Then `(letter == 'X' or letter == 'O')` is true, so `not (letter == 'X' or letter == 'O')` is false, and you break out of the while loop.
- But `(letter != 'X' or letter != 'O')` is true because `letter != 'O'` is true.

More generally, `not (A or B)` is not equivalent to `not A or not B`.